# How to play music using pygame (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, audio

I am trying to play an .mp3 file using pygame. Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('MSM.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

pygame.event.wait()
```

This however does not actually play the file. The audio file is located within the same folder as the .py file.

Comment: If I remove `pygame.init()` this plays files just fine.

Comment: From the Pygame docs:

"Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead."

Answer (score 1):

The pyGame docs suggest using the pygame.mixer.pre_init() method before the top-level pygame.init() on some platforms.

> "Some platforms require the pygame.mixer module for loading and
>   playing sounds module to be initialized after the display modules have
>   initialized. The top level pygame.init() takes care of this
>   automatically, but cannot pass any arguments to the mixer init. To
>   solve this, mixer has a function pygame.mixer.pre_init() to set the
>   proper defaults before the toplevel init is used."
>   https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init